# How to check if every element in an array is lower than another array in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

Right now I have the following idea:

```
int WORK[] = new int[]{5, 4, 3};
int release[] = new int[]{3, 2, 3};
boolean check = false;

for (int i = 0; i < WORK.length; i++)
{
     if (WORK[i] >= release[i]) 
     {
        for (int j = 0; j < WORK.length; j++)
        {
           if (WORK[j] >= release[j]) 
           {
               for (int k = 0; k < WORK.length; k++)
               {
                   if (WORK[k] >= release[k])
                   {
                       check = true;
                       System.out.print("All elements in work are bigger than release");
                       break;
                   }   
               }
               break;    
           } 
        }
        break;    
     }
}

if(!check)
{
     System.out.print("Not every element in work is bigger than release");
}
```

Now I want to know if there is a more efficient way to do this? But my main problem is that I need to do this with `n` elements. With `n´ elements it is not efficient neither useful, because I don't know how many elements will be there.

What I want to know is there a function in Java `Arrays` or something, which could help me?

Any help?

Comment: You should decide if you call your arrays `work` or `WORK` and `need` or `release`. And wouldn't it make much more sense to find the lowest/highest number of the `need` array first and then check that number with each element of the other array?

Comment: Your code references the `release` array, but it isn't defined in the snippet. Can you elaborate on what exactly you're trying to do?

Comment: Agree with @Tom. First find the minimum of the `need` then check the numbers of `work` against that minimum. This way you are going to do it by O(n) in time and O(1) in space which can be something.

Comment: Are you comparing each element in `work` with the corresponding element in `need`, or each `work` element with *all* the elements in `need` ? Besides, your logic (or at least the output message) seems broken, as you declare that "all elements are bigger" after finding one element that is bigger (and `break`ing after that).

Comment: Sorry for that, it was because the part of iterations I copied from my source code and only added the snippet and System.out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I got your question correctly.

```
if (array1.length == array2.length) {
    for (int i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
        for (int j =0; j < array2.length; j++) {
            // compare array1[i] with array2[j];
        }
    }
} else {
    System.out.println("Arrays have different lengths.");
}
```

This gives you the opportunity to compare all numbers of one array with all numbers of the second. So your basic idea was not that bad.

Hope it helps.

This one seems very basic, but it should do it.

Answer (score 2):

With Java 8, you can do this in a functional style with streams (this would *not* be a performance optimization; it's just less code to write).

```
IntPredicate lowerThanRelease = i -> IntStream.of(release).allMatch(j -> i <= j);
boolean allLower = IntStream.of(work).allMatch(lowerThanRelease);
```

Comment: @MSach you mean like... explain lambdas or paste the javadoc for `Stream.allMatch` ?

Comment: This snippet only works if the first test fails. You cannot reuse `Stream`. So you have to make a new `Stream` in every iteration of allMatch.

Answer (score 1):

One efficient way to do this is two have 4 variables
workmax, workmin, needmax, needmin.

Iterate through both arrays one at a time and find the max and min values within that array. Then all you need to do is compare the min value of one array with max value of the second array 
This way you just need two loops (no nesting).
Then its a matter of simple comparison.
e.g. 
if (workmin > needmax) then System.out.print("All elements in " + work + "are bigger than need");

I think you can come up with the code if you understand the approach mentioned above.